# How to store data read from RFID using java and RS232 port

Tags: java, serial-port

Can anybody help me how can i store  data read from RFID using java and RS232 port.
The problem with my code is,i am storing data in the  string and each time when the data is read replaces the previous data that is read. what can i do 
thank you

```
for(int j=0;j<=3;j++)
{
char c =  (char) in.read();
String s = Integer.toHexString(c).toUpperCase();       
info=  (s.length() == 1 ? "0" : "") + s;
```

Comment: Show the relevant portion of your code.

Comment: Hello and welcome to stackoverflow. In order to get useful answers to your questions could you please review the guidelines on how to ask a question - http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: i have added my code